# WPF - Events from inside User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, events, wpf-controls

we have a problem when trying to create events for a custom control in WPF. We have our code like this:

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent KeyPressedEvent =
            EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
                "keyPressed", RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
                    typeof(KeyEventHandler), typeof(Keyboard));
```

```
    public event KeyEventHandler keyPressed
    {
        add { AddHandler(KeyPressedEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(KeyPressedEvent, value); }
    }

void btnAlphaClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var btn = (Button)sender;
        Key key = (Key)Enum.Parse(typeof(Key), btn.Content.ToString().ToUpper());
        PresentationSource source = null;
        foreach (PresentationSource s in PresentationSource.CurrentSources)
        {
            source = s;
        }
        RaiseEvent(new KeyEventArgs(InputManager.Current.PrimaryKeyboardDevice, source,0,key));
```

The control is an on screen keyboard, and we basically need to pass out to the  KeyPressedEventArgs to the subscribers to the event detailing what key was pressed (we can't find much that helps us with this in WPF, only winforms).

Any help, greatly appreciated!

Comment: Probably the correct events are PreviewKeyUp and PreviewKeyDown. Also I would use tunneling events instead of bubble. I am not sure exactly, I will check my assumptions later.

Comment: Have you tried "KeyGestures" ?

Comment: Just got into the office. But thanks for the interest guys, I'll check out those mentioned above

Comment: Hey Guys! Finally got it working! :D If anyone checks back here, it was this tutorial which got it done for me: http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?Id=79

Comment: If the above link solved your problem, post it as one of the answers and then accept your own answer. Users looking for similar problem won't have to go through the comments and can directly look at the accepted answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Step 1: Add Event Handler to OK and Cancel Button

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{     
}

private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{     
}
```

Add the public property in the UserControl1.xaml.cs file to share the value of the textbox with the host

```
public string UserName
{
    get { return txtName.Text; }
    set { txtName.Text = value; }
}
```

Declare the Events for Ok and Cancel Buttons which can be subscribed by Windows Form.

```
public event EventHandler OkClick;
public event EventHandler CancelClick;
```

Now add the code to the event handler so that we can raise the event to host also.

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (OkClick != null)
        OkClick(this, e);
}

private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (CancelClick != null)
        CancelClick(this, e);
}
```

Step 2: Handle the WPF Control Event in Windows Form

Add Handler to `OKClick` and `CancelClick` Events just after creating the instance of the user control

```
_WPFUserControl.OkClick += new EventHandler(OnOkHandler);
_WPFUserControl.CancelClick += new EventHandler(OnCancelHandler);
```

Write code in the handler method. Here I user the `UserName` property in the OK button handler so show the how to share the values also.

```
protected void OnOkHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hello: " +_WPFUserControl.UserName + " you clicked Ok Button");
}

protected void OnCancelHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("you clicked Cancel Button");
}
```

Reference:
http://a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?Id=79

Comment: Don't forget to mark this an accepted answer; if you can summarize quickly what specifically helped, do that too -- that host might not always exist, or it might change all its URLs at some point.